# Trouble understanding how a big-o bound proves a limit

Tags: number-theory, limits, asymptotics

I’m trying to understand the answer to exercise 4.5.2-10(c) in Knuth’s *The Art of Computer Programming*. Let $q_n$ denote the number of ordered pairs of integers $(u,v)$ in the range $1\leq u,v \leq n$ such that $u$ and $v$ are relatively prime. We’re trying to prove that

$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{q_n}{n^2} = \sum_{k\geq 1} \frac{\mu (k)}{k^2} $$

where $\mu$ denotes the Möbius function. We already showed in part (b) that $q_n = \sum_{k\geq 1} \mu (k)\lfloor n/k \rfloor ^2$.

I’ve already read the (rather terse) answer that Knuth provides, in which he asserts that

$$q_n - \sum_{k\geq 1} \mu (k) (n/k)^2 = O(n H_n) - O(n).$$

I have convinced myself on paper that this is true, but I’m having trouble understanding how this proves the limit. Since $nH_n$ increases as a function of $n$, it seems to me that this should imply the two functions only get further apart as $n$ increases. Any insight would be much appreciated :)

Comment: $H_n = o(n)$, so $O(nH_n) = o(n^2)$; also $O(n) = o(n^2)$. Then you get the claim dividing both sides of the last equality by $n^2$.

Comment: In other words, your worry is that the absolute error is large—but that's not a problem, because the relative error is small.

Comment: @zhoraster Thanks for your help! I just need another nudge for the VERY last step. The equality can be manipulated to become $q_n/n^2 - \sum_{k\geq 1} \mu(k) / k^2 = o(1)$, which implies that the the difference $\leq c$ for some positive real $c$. Now given an $\epsilon > 0$ how do I use this to get $q_n/n^2$ within $\epsilon$ of $\sum_{k\geq 1}\mu(k) / k^2$? Thanks and sorry if I'm not catching something that is entirely obvious!

Comment: Sorry about my last comment, I mixed up my definitions of big-o and little-o. Little-o means that for any choice of $c$ the inequality holds, i.e. for all $\epsilon > 0$ we have the difference $\leq \epsilon$, which proves the limit. Edit: @zhoraster Would you be able to post the comment as an answer so I can accept it? (I think this is how it works -- I'm new to the site.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$H_n=o(n)$, so $O(nH_n)=o(n^2)$; also $O(n)=o(n^2)$. Then you get the claim dividing both sides of the last equality by  $n^2$.